# Compile error : `string' does not name a type

Tags: c++

I have 2 compile errors that I have been trying to fix and not getting anywhere. 
Here are the 2 errors
'string' does not name a type on line 80
`s' undeclared (first use this function)  on line 87

Could someone please point me in the right direction

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


//class type declared
  class Meeting
  {
    private:
     string speaker;
     string topic;
     string venue;
     string date;
   public:
    Meeting();
    void setSpeaker(string s);
    void setTopic(string t);
    void setVenue(string v);
    void setDate(string d);
    string getSpeaker();
    string getTopic();
    string getVenue();
    string getDate();

 };

   //member functions for class Meeting
   Meeting::Meeting()
   {
    string speaker = " ";
    string topic = " ";


string venue = " ";
  string date = " ";
}

//mutators to set member variables to vale given
void Meeting::setSpeaker(string s)
{
     speaker = s;
}
void Meeting::setTopic(string t)
{
     topic = t;
}
void Meeting::setVenue(string v)
{
     venue = v;
}
void Meeting::setDate(string d)
{
     date = d;
}


//Accessors to retrieve data from each of the member variables
string Meeting::getSpeaker()
{
    return speaker;
}
string Meeting::getTopic()
{
    return topic;
}
string Meeting::getVenue()
{
    return venue;
}
string Meeting::getDate()
{
    return date;
}


//main using the class
int main()
{
         Meeting mMeeting; //instance of Meeting Class
   Meeting
         string s;     // error `string' does not name a type 
         string t;
         string v;
         string d;

    // Enter Meeting Information
    cout << "Enter Speaker name and surname: ";
         getline(cin, s);     // error `s' undeclared (first use this function) 
         mMeeting.setSpeaker(s);
    cout << "Enter Topic: ";
         cin >> t;
         mMeeting.setTopic(t);
    cout << "Enter Venue: ";
         cin >> v;
         mMeeting.setVenue(v);
    cout << "Enter Date: ";
         cin >> d;
         mMeeting.setDate(d);


    //Display Meeting details
    cout << "\nSpeaker at meeting: " << mMeeting.getSpeaker() << endl;
    cout << "Topic at meeting: " << mMeeting.getTopic() << endl;
    cout << "Venue of meeting: " << mMeeting.getVenue() << endl;
    cout << "Date of meeting: " << mMeeting.getDate() << endl;

 system ("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that stray `Meeting` supposed to be there above the definition of `s`?

Comment: As an aside, I'd advise against `using namespace std` outside of local scope: the extra `std::` doesn't hurt, and it reminds both you and the readers of your code that you are using some standard library stuff here.  Not to mention IDE completion, header file ordering, new `std` header file types conflicting with your own types, etc.

Comment: It's a good lesson. Often when  a compiler says an error is on one line, it's the previous line that is actually wrong.

Comment: Why has this question got three down votes?

Comment: @john Presumably because it's a code dump with a request to debug. It also fits the description of "too localized": "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors".

Comment: I don't see what the OP could have done differently. He presumably had no clue. If it's the policy to only allow questions that might be useful to future visitors then I think we'd lose 80% of the questions asked.

Comment: @john the bare minimum would be to narrow the problem down to a small code sample that reproduces the problem. OP would have probably found the solution that way.

Comment: I think that was beyond this particular poster. It was a very basic error and he didn't see it, despite spending some time on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the errors mentioned by the others, here's a semantic error:

```
Meeting::Meeting()
{
    string speaker = " ";
    string topic = " ";
    string venue = " ";
    string date = " ";
}
```

Here, you intend on assigning the class members the value `" "`, but what you're actually doing is defining 4 local string variables and initializing them with `" "`. To get expected results, you should do this:

```
Meeting::Meeting()
{
    speaker = " ";
    topic = " ";
    venue = " ";
    date = " ";
}
```

The above function body assigns the 4 class members the values as you intend to do.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the logic errors. I am very new with classes and objects.

Comment: You're quite welcome.

Answer (score 4):

that's because of this line

```
    Meeting mMeeting; //instance of Meeting Class
   Meeting //this line is creating error, remove this line
     string s;     // error `string' does not name a type
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It sorted the problem out

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Meeting` on line 79 and it would compile.